# node js aes-256-cbc encrypt buffer and plain text

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

encryption_key = 0F777D55FDB154E7D8754C3C0E660A65

data = 112233440220160120165502121122334455660811223344156D6173746572706173735F757365720104800000000000

iv = 00000000000000000000000000000000

result = 4A2D82F722F2720E58CE3170A2398783B5F8F1D40404D90A03019C1082DA47D3E855BD8A09F294D3B06076144286F7F1

when i run these values at an online aes calculator the result is matched
http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index?key=0F777D55FDB154E7D8754C3C0E660A65&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=112233440220160120165502121122334455660811223344156D6173746572706173735F757365720104800000000000&mode=cbc&action=Encrypt&output=

but the node js code does not work:

```
var crypto, ALGORITHM, KEY;

crypto = require('crypto');

ALGORITHM = 'AES-256-CBC';
KEY = new Buffer('0F777D55FDB154E7D8754C3C0E660A65');

var IV = new Buffer('0000000000000000');
var cipher_text;
var encryptor;

encryptor = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM, KEY, IV);
encryptor.setEncoding('utf8');
encryptor.write('112233440220160120165502121122334455660811223344156D6173746572706173735F757365720104800000000000');
encryptor.end();

cipher_text = encryptor.read();
console.log(cipher_text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoding of the Latin1 "0" character is different from the 0x00 byte that you seem to be using in your example. You should provide the IV data as hex:

```
var IV = new Buffer('00000000000000000000000000000000', 'hex');
```

By the way, your key is only 32 hexits long (16 actual bytes), so you're using AES-128 and not AES-256: `ALGORITHM = 'AES-128-CBC';`

---

#### Security considerations:

Using a fixed IV is not semantically secure. You need to use an unpredictable (read: random) IV for CBC mode. Since the IV doesn't need to be secret, you can send it along with the ciphertext. A common way is to prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.

Additionally, you should encrypt in such a way as to detect (malicious) changes to the ciphertext. This is usually achieved by using authenticated encryption through an authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or applying an encrypt-then-MAC scheme with a strong MAC like HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: Yes. Also, [use authenticated encryption](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken).